# Having problems with the loop function

Tags: python

I have a problem with  looping through my lists in my text files. I am missing something but i cant figure out what it is. Here is my script

```
user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')
# username = user.readline() 
password_list = password.readline()
pa = ''.join(password_list)


for users in  user:
    for pass_list in pa:
        login_data = users + pass_list
        print login_data
```

This is what I get for my output

```
User2@mymail.com
P
User2@mymail.com
a
User2@mymail.com
s
User2@mymail.com
s
User2@mymail.com
w
User2@mymail.com
o
User2@mymail.com
r
User2@mymail.com
d
User2@mymail.com
1
User2@mymail.com


User3@mymail.com
P
User3@mymail.com
a
User3@mymail.com
s
User3@mymail.com
s
User3@mymail.com
w
User3@mymail.com
o
User3@mymail.com
r
User3@mymail.com
d
User3@mymail.com
1
User3@mymail.com
```

What I would like to see it print is

```
User4@mymail.com
Password1
user5@mymail.com
Password1
etc .........
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `password_list = password.readlines()` (not `readline`)

Comment: It's also super disorienting to have lines like `for users in  user:` and `for pass_list in pa:`, where the name of the list seems like it should be the name of the item in the list, and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')
username = user.readlines() 
password_list = password.readlines()

for username in  user:
    for pass_val in password_list:
        login_data = username+'\n'+ pass_val
        print login_data
```

Answer (score 3):

`password` is a file-like object. `password_list` takes the top line from that file. `pa` joins that line with a `''` -- since that line is a string, this takes all the characters one by one, then joins them together with nothing separating them, giving you exactly what you started with. Then you iterate over that string -- but iterating over a string produces each character in that string, which is exactly what you're getting.

Try:

```
with open('users.txt', 'r') as users, open('password.txt', 'r') as passwords:
    user_data = zip(users, passwords)
    for user, password in user_data:
        print(user, password)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to print out the contents of two lists concurrently.  You can use `zip()`:

```
user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')
# username = user.readline() 
password_list = password.readline()

for users, pa in zip(user, password_list):
    login_data = users + pass_list
    print login_data
```

What is happening with your code is that this loop:

```
for pass_list in pa:
```

will iterate over the characters in the string `pa`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a string in Python will yield the string's characters one by one. You could just do:

```
password_list = password.readlines()
```

This returns a list of lines over which you can easily iterate with a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
for users in  user:
    login_data = users + pa
    print login_data
```

If not can you post a snippet of both users.txt and password.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my nested loop does what I wanted

```
user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')


for users in user:
    for pass_list in password:
        login_data = users + '\n' + pass_list
        print login_data
```